# Check a projectID property is not null or empty in search rest api of sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-rest-api

I write this different queries for projectID in a site.

```
/_api/search/query?querytext='*'&$filter = projectID ne null&sourceid='d453a7990-05ea-4af9-81ef-edfab16c4e31'
```

Or

```
_api/search/query?querytext='sourceid='d453a7990-05ea-4af9-81ef-edfab16c4e31' AND projectID <> null'
```

Or

```
"/_api/search/query?querytext=''ViewXml':'&lt;View&gt;&lt;Query&gt;&lt;Where&gt;&lt;IsNotNull&gt;&lt;FieldRef Name='ProjectID' /&gt;&lt;/IsNotNull&gt;&lt;/Where&gt;&lt;/Query&gt;&lt;/View&gt;'&sourceid='d453a7990-05ea-4af9-81ef-edfab16c4e31''
```

But nothing work. Kindly help

Comment: i don't think it will be null instead add filter for empty projectID ne ''

Answer (score 2):

First enable Search and Query property for **ViewsLifeTime** managed property in search service and perform full crawl.

Use Search Query API for not returning the items for which **ViewsLifeTime** count is null

```
https://domain.com/_api/search/query?querytext='NOT(viewslifetime:0)'
```

References:

- [How to filter on empty string value list items using Rest API](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/4690e596-aeae-49e7-9057-f31352d92e07/how-to-filter-on-empty-string-value-list-items-using-rest-api?forum=appsforsharepoint)
- [Filter with empty value using REST API](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/169259/filter-with-empty-value-using-rest-api)

Comment: Hi Sathish, I have implemented ViewsLiffeTime, however below search don't return desire result:                                                                     
_api/search/query?querytext=%27NOT(viewslifetime:0)%27&$filter=ProjectID%20ne%20%27%27&rowlimit=500&selectproperties=%27ProjectID'&contentclass=STS_ListItem&trimduplicates=true